# Is WebView behavior identical to Safari

Tags: macos, safari, webview

Our Mac OS application displays user interface inside WebView component.

Can we rely on the fact that WebView behaves exactly as Safari content pane on any Mac?
Can we expect the same set of plugins installed in Safari and inside WebView of our application?

In other words, is the same WebView shared by all applications on Mac OS, including Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A WebView object is intended to
>   support most features you would expect
>   in a web browser except that it
>   doesn’t implement the specific user
>   interface for those features. You are
>   responsible for implementing the user
>   interface objects such as status bars,
>   toolbars, buttons, and text fields.
>   For example, a WebView object manages
>   a back-forward list by default, and
>   has goBack: and goForward: action
>   methods. It is your responsibility to
>   create the buttons that would send
>   theses action messages. Note, there is
>   some overhead in maintaining a
>   back-forward list and page cache, so
>   you should disable it if your
>   application doesn’t use it."

A WebView uses webkit engine to render html which is what safari also uses. Hence most of the functionality will be the same.